# How do I resolve an XML::Parser::Expat error: "Use of tied on a handle without * is deprecated"?

Tags: xml, perl

While trying to execute below code, I am getting the following error message:

```
Use of tied on a handle without * is deprecated at C:/Perl/lib/XML/Parser/Expat.pm.
```

I have heard that this can be resolved by installing v2.41 of XML::Parser. How do I install a specific version of XML::Parser?

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
my $FileName = 'sample.xls';
my $xml_file = 'hello.xml';
my $par=$ARGV[0];
my $xml = XMLin(
    $xml_file,
    KeepRoot => 1,
    ForceArray => 1,
);
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse($FileName);
die "Parser not Defined", ".\n" if ( !defined $workbook );

    for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

        # Find out the worksheet ranges
        my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();
        for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
            for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
                my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
                next unless $cell;
        $xml->{$par} = $cell->value();

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install a specific version, you just need to install the newest, and the following will do that:

```
cpan XML::Parser
```

The change log does indeed indicate that this error is fixed in 2.41 (which happens to be the newest version).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.. Nothing special to install.. ActivePerl version 5.14.2 has all the supported and updated packages.. This will work. Even 5.14.1 version dont have all the updated packages. So please use 5.14.2 only.